# how to display avatar depending on gender and age in play 2.0 framework application?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working on a play 2.0 framework application in java. I want to display the default profile pic depending on their gender and age, like man or woman or boy or girl pics as a default pic (like facebook etc.).

How would I go about generating a different URL for the image, based on the attributes of the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your User model, have a method

```
public String getProfilePictureURL() {
    if ("male".equals(gender) && age >= 18) return "url for man image";
    else if ("male".equals(gender) && age < 18) return "url for boy image";    
    else if ("female".equals(gender) && age >= 18) return "url for woman image";
    else if ("female".equals(gender) && age > 18) return "url for girl image";
    else return null;
}
```

I am assuming you have `gender` and `age` attributes in your User model class. Make sure you put in the correct

Then, in your view, you can just say

```
<img src="@user.getProfilePictureURL()" />
```